# Pattern rules and directories

Tags: makefile

I'm using macOS default built-in version of make (if it makes any difference). I'm trying to make a makefile to manage super-tiny projects in separate directories, that are contained by another directory with a makefile in it. So, instead of writing information about each project – that would take forever – I've gone with pattern rules. But whenever there is a directory in target dependencies, it just goes crazy, saying "nothing to be done to target" or "target is up to date". For example:

```
%: %.c
    gcc -o $@ $<
```

works just fine. But, if i do this:

```
%: %/%.c
    gcc -o $@ $<
```

"target is up to date", whatever I do. I've tried making it `.PHONY`, and no result. I've even tried doing this:

```
define FUNC
$1: $1/$1.c
    gcc -o $1 $1.c
endef
%:
    $(call FUNC,$@)
```

And again, nothing changes, even if I make it `.PHONY` again. (Not like `.PHONY: %`, of course, something like `.PHONY: a` and then i try doing `make a`) Why doesn't the second example work? Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that because Apple is so scared of GPLv3 software, the version of GNU make that comes with MacOS is very old.  Not only that but I've seen reports that patches they've applied to their version have broken it.  I urge you to use Homebrew or MacPorts (or build it yourself from source) to get a more modern, supported version of GNU make.

However that won't help you here.  First you can only have one `%` in each target or prerequisite of the pattern.  The second and subsequent ones are not replaced, so a prerequisite like `%/%.c` is not legal.

For your second attempt, that doesn't make any sense.  You can't define a make rule inside a recipe: recipes are passed to the shell to execute so they're shell syntax, not makefile syntax.

But beyond that, your rule is fundamentally problematic.  Consider what it would look like if you were to write an explicit rule:

```
foo: foo/foo.c
        gcc -o foo foo/foo.c
```

Here you're creating an executable `foo` with the same name as a directory `foo` that already exists (presumably).  Even if you were to run that `gcc` directly from the shell, it would fail because of this, not even considering make.

That's the reason make is saying "nothing to do": that target `foo` already exists (it's a directory) and make can't find a rule to update it (because `foo/%.c` doesn't exist so the pattern rule doesn't apply).  Since it exists and there's no rule to update it, there's nothing for make to do.

So you'll need to rethink what exactly it is you want to accomplish here.